# Нейронная сеть на основе ruby-fann: данные на выходе разнятся

Tags: ruby, fann

Пишу скрипт виртуального игрока (AI) Tic Tac Toe, базирующийся на нейронной сети на основе **ruby-fann**. Принцип работы следующий: после запуска программа рандомно проигрывает несколько десятков тысяч партий (это одна - две минуты) сама с собой, [записывая](https://github.com/cmirnow/Tic-Tac-Toe-AI-with-Neural-Network/blob/master/bin/training.rb) ход игры и сопутствующую информацию в csv-файл, и в дальнейшем руководствуется следующей логикой: все (или хотя бы часть) оптимальные ходы уже находятся в лог-файле, задача только в том, чтобы правильным образом их оттуда извлечь, в чем и заключена роль рубиновой обертки FANN. Такой вот несколько философский принцип призван внести разнообразие в бесконечную череду аналогичных программ для игры в крестики-нолики.

Программа на данный момент вполне работоспособна, играя вторым номером (т.е. ноликами) - в большинстве случаев успешно сведет партию к ничьей; либо выиграет, если соперник-человек допустит ошибку, либо попросит переформировать (порой весьма помогает) csv-файл. А вопрос в следующем:

Время от времени, несмотря на то, что [на входе](https://github.com/cmirnow/Tic-Tac-Toe-AI-with-Neural-Network/blob/master/bin/game.rb#L147) полностью идентичные (одни и те же csv-файл, механизмы чтения данных и формирования массива приоритетов ходов для дальнейшего скармливания FANN) данные - на выходе нейронная сеть выдает различные ответы. Подобное случается нечасто, но хотелось бы понять, это сбои в работе NN либо знаковая особенность ее работы? Адекватные советы, рекомендации? - заранее благодарен.

Comment: Это нормально для нейронных сетей. Это достаточно ненадежная и сложно отлаживаемая технология для того, чтоб возникали ошибки, которые можно сразу и не заметить. И еще нейронные сети имеют малый круг эффективного применения (например, и к крестикам-ноликам не подходит), что видно уже потому, что задан этот вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но я позволю себе напомнить, что на страничке ruby-fann в качестве иллюстрации предлагается именно Tic Tac Toe: https://github.com/tangledpath/ruby-fann Там довольно старый, архаичный проект на основе rails 4, сходу мне не удалось запустить его, потому и начал кодить свой.

Comment: Получил на email негативное послание от модераторов, после чего без предупреждений оказался удален как мой коммент, содержащий недоумение в контексте крайне неумелой, непрофессиональной правки заголовка моего текста одним из участников сообщества, но и коммент участника, который признает вину и приносит извинения. Ну, что здесь сказать; русский стиль. Много лет пользовался англоязычное версией Stackoverflow, и весьма жалею, что сделал в НГ исключение для русскоязычного сообщества. Позорище. Гуд лаг; кстати, прошу удалить мой вопрос, я не доверяю своего контента команде русских холопов.

Answer (score 0):

Если веса сохранены как в keras h5 файле и неизменяются->сеть,выход один и тот же,если этот файл изменяется то бишь веса->естественно разные результаты.

Comment: Как уже говорил, scv-файл формируется один раз и работает в неизменном виде до тех пор, пока не удален, методы обработки данных, хранящихся в этом файле - также не меняются.  Но выходные данные нейронной сети, получающие данным посредством описанных процессов - способны быть различными. Где в моем вопросе вы увидели хоть что-либо напоминающее "keras h5"?

Comment: Я про аналогию говорил,csv и где веса хранятся это разные вещи.